# IntelliJ 2016.2 Getter and Setter code generation?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, configuration, getter-setter, intellij-idea-2016

When you're inside a Java class you can press

ALT+Insert --> Generate... --> Getter and Setter

In an older version of Intellij I remember that when I created a "getter and setter" it was created where the cursor is in that moment that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> was pressed. But now they are created under the fields the "getter and setter" are created for.

How can you change this behavior so that getter and setter is created where the cursor is in that moment that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> was pressed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using the latest version myself, but maybe something [like this](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/10/arrange-your-code-automatically-with-intellij-idea-12/) is also applied for 2016.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>

in the left menu to navigate to

Code Style -> Java

and press the tab "Arrangement"

remove the field where the field and the public are grouped

[image]
[image]

Now public getter and setter is created where the cursor is